# Paypal REST API error 400 : Invalid start date

Tags: javascript, node.js, paypal

My application frequently crashes when i redirect the user to the paypal payment page. I have the following error :

`Error: Response Status : 400`

```
[ { field: 'start_date', issue:
 'start date is required, should be valid and greater than the current date. Should be consistent with ISO 8601 Format' } ]
```

Yet, I format the date as is shown in the Github example file

```
 var isoDate = new Date(Date.now())
    isoDate.setSeconds(isoDate.getSeconds() + 4);
    isoDate.toISOString().slice(0, 19) + 'Z';
```

I even added some seconds to be sure the date is greater than the current date

var isoDate = new Date(Date.now()+10000)
    isoDate.setSeconds(isoDate.getSeconds() + 4);
    isoDate.toISOString().slice(0, 19) + 'Z';

console.log(isoDate);

I don't understand this error that occurs not every time but very often, so i really can't release my app without fixing it.

Comment: Which PayPal API method are you calling?

Comment: Did you try to encode URL?

Answer (score 1):

Please fix the code like follows:

```
 var isoDate = new Date(Date.now())
    isoDate.setHours(isoDate.getHours() + 4);
    isoDate = isoDate.toISOString().slice(0, 19) + 'Z';
```